# what is the latest version of WinForms? And how does this relate the version of .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms

What is the latest version of WinForms?  And how does this relate the version of .NET?

For example in VS2008 with .NET 3.5 is there Windows Forms 3.5 under the bonnet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Forms is just a subset of the Framework Class Library and yes, the current version is 3.5.

**WPF Update**

A new presentation technology has been added to .Net since 2.0 called WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) It is the newer way to create .Net UIs and which is also used by Silverlight.

[WPF described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)

Comment: ok - so I should really look for a programming Windows Forms 3.5 text then...thanks

Comment: Copied from below: 2.0 will be fine for forms programming for you. Little has changed there. The biggies are LINQ, WCF, WPF... ah. There you go. WPF. Windows Presentation Foundation. That's the "new" forms engine. You might want to take a look at that before diving into the "older" forms technology.

Comment: Microsoft call it the 'Framework' Class Library.  'Foundation' can be confused with WPF etc.

Comment: Note that you do want .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a separate version number for Windows Forms. Why would there be?

Comment: I just wasn't sure as a newbie - I'm looking for a good book (ideally available in PDF) for Windows Forms programming in VS2008 with .NET 3.5.  All I seem to be able to see so far is "windows forms 2.0" type books...

Comment: 2.0 will be fine for forms programming for you. Little has changed there. The biggies are LINQ, WCF, WPF... ah. There you go. WPF. Windows Presentation Foundation. That's the "new" forms engine. You might want to take a look at that before diving into the "older" forms technology.

Answer (score 1):

.Net provide a bouquet of different technologies to do your job. Winforms is a technology that lets you create desktop applications, and so does WPF. ASP.net allows you to create web applications and WPF is for creating workflow foundation programming etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

On my PC with .NET 3.5 SP1 installed, System.Windows.Forms is version: 1.0.5000.0 in the Global assembly cache.  The actual file version (and Product version) of 'System.Windows.Forms.dll' is 1.1.4322.2032.

It is unrelated to the overall .NET version, there is no Windows Forms 3.5 although Microsoft would say there is, ie Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

If you need to build classic Windows desktop applications you would use Windows Forms.

If you need to build more modern looking desktop applications that support text flow layouts, richer formatting and styling and graphical animation then Windows Presentation Foundation is the better choice.